# android need advice to start develop using gestures

Tags: android, gesture-recognition

I have a `canvas.DrawText.` I want to use gestures to dynamically change the text color and font. This is all working nice using a popup view class. But I want to make this more direct maybe using Fling scroll.

There are millions of colors and by sliding finger on the screen I thought I could increase/decrease the colorInteger and send it to `paint.setColor(colorInteger );` before I draw. I have tried all day using various methods.

I have `public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {`

I know I must catch the x/y in `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`

Wanted to use the screen left edge for color change and screen right for Font change. I have 21 ttf fonts.

The thing is, I see there is the `OnGestureListener onscroll` implementation but that will disable my `onTouchEvent` right? I have lots of movement going on in there.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GestureDetector`. Implement a `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener` and catch gestures there.

```
class MyActivity extends Activity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {

    // ....
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), this);
```

Provide GestureDetector with touch events like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event))
        return true;
    else return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

In `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener`'s `onDown` you must return `true` if you want to process this gesture. E.g. then the user puts his finger donw in a specified area return `true`, and `false` otherwise. If `false` is returned here, complicated sequences (like fling or scroll) started with this event will not be detected.

Comment: thanks. In my onTouchEvent UP/DOWN/MOVE im moving text on a Canvas.drawText. The GestureDetector dont have an ACTION_MOVE or is that the onFling? Have been trying to use but cannot wrap my head around it.

Comment: I did what you sad and i think it's working like a want.
I placed the ...return gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(event);... at the end of onTouchEvent method so i can still use the code in onTouchEvent and still the gestureDetector is fireing. Splendid!! For anyone looking how i did it, se this [link](http://www.androidsnippets.com/gesturedetector-and-gesturedetectorongesturelistener)

Comment: There are no separate ACTION_MOVE here. There are `onFling` and `onScroll` methods, they are aimed to notify about a whole gesture. In each of these method you are getting `MotionEvent` with all moves, which caused current gesture.